# javaScript problem - setItem is overwriting localstorage

Tags: javascript

I've got a problem with a tiny school project my group is doing.

Whenever i submit my input to localstorage, it overwrites the previous localStorage item.
The idea is to later "merge" a member-input with a task-input by using check-boxes etc..

I want to be able to list up numerous names and tasks form localstorage, but its not possible now as u see, and I am a bit stuck

This is my first post so i am very sorry for any inconvenience
Thanks in advance!

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/testStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Arbeidskrav webprojekt</h1>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Oppgavebeskrivelse</legend>
            <input id="firstValue" type="text" placeholder="Oppgave">
            <button id="firstBtn" type="button">Legg til oppgave</button>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Medlemsnavn</legend>
            <input id="secondValue" type="text" placeholder="Medlemsnavn">
            <button id="secondBtn" type="button">Legg til medlem</button>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Arbeidsoppgaver</legend>
            <div id="taskOutput"></div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Teammedlemmer</legend>
            <div id="teamOutput"></div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fordelte arbeidsoppgaver</legend>
            <div id="combinedOutput"></div>
        </fieldset>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          const firstValue = document.getElementById("firstValue");
          const secondValue = document.getElementById("secondValue");

          const firstBtn = document.getElementById("firstBtn");
          const secondBtn = document.getElementById("secondBtn");

          const taskOutput = document.getElementById("taskOutput");
          const teamOutput = document.getElementById("teamOutput");
          const combinedOutput = document.getElementById("combinedOutput");


          firstBtn.onclick = function(){
              const keyOne = "task";
              const valueOne = firstValue.value;

              if(valueOne){
                  localStorage.setItem(keyOne, valueOne);
                  location.reload();
              }else{
                  alert("Enter a valid task");
              }
          };

          secondBtn.onclick = function(){
              const keyTwo = "name";
              const valueTwo = secondValue.value;

              if(valueTwo){
                  localStorage.setItem(keyTwo, valueTwo);
                  location.reload();
              }else{
                  alert("Enter a valid name");
              }
          };

          for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

              const key = localStorage.key(i);
              const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
              if(key == "task"){
                  taskOutput.innerHTML += `${value}<br>`;
              }else{
                  teamOutput.innerHTML += `${value}<br>`;
              }
          }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` stores data in string format, which means every time you are calling `setItem()`, the method it will overwrite the previous data.

First, you need to check if your `localStorage` exists or not.

Then if that particular `localStorage` does not exist, then create the that particular `localStorage` using `setItem()` the method.

Now, if already that particular `localStorage` exist, then use method `getItem()` and store the `localStorage` in any variable.

Then, add the new value you wanted to add to `localStorage`, in the above variable.

After, that use the above variable to store `localStorage`, using `setItem()` method.

Check below code you can do something similar.

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem('names')){
  localStorage.setItem('names', 'John Doe;');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('names'));
}
else{
  let namesStr = localStorage.getItem('names');
  
  let newName = "Katy Clark;";
  
  namesStr += newName;
  localStorage.setItem('names', namesStr);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('names'));
}
```

> I am using delimiter **;** so that I can find out a different name. You can use any delimiter accordingly

Comment: Thanks alot! That was very helpful!! <3

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps to you.

instead of key, value(string), take value as array.

```
Ex: localStorage.setItem("key",["value1","value2"]);

console.log(localStorage);
length: 1
key: "value1,value2" (localStorage stores data in string format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `push` method, to insert an element at the end of your data structure.